# react redux store updates once and then stops updating

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have an example of a `tui-counter` done using `react-blessed` and I'd like to connect redux to it. The code is [here](https://github.com/zcaudate/example-react-blessed-redux/).

[image]

When I press on any button - say `INC`, it updates once and then stops updating. It seems that the counter state is incrementing but it's not rendering to the ui. Below is an example of the output. I don't know where I have gotten the wiring wrong I suspect [here](https://github.com/zcaudate/example-react-blessed-redux/blob/master/src/main.js#L153) but I've tried a couple of things and it hasn't worked because I'm not sure if it's a redux issue or a blessed issue. Any tips would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer, and I implemented React-Redux v7.

By bizarre coincidence, I actually debugged this *exact* issue for someone else recently over in Reactiflux (or at least I *think* it was someone else).

The first problem here is that you need to be using the "alternate renderer" entry point for React-Redux, because the primary entry point assumes you're using `react-dom` or `react-native`.  So, you need `import { connect } from "react-redux/lib/alternate-renderers"`.

However, even once you do that, there is actually a bug in `react-blessed`, combined with a sort of deficiency in React-Redux.  The result is that React-Redux's `<Provider>` ends up unsubscribing itself from the store after the first action is dispatched, which causes all further dispatched actions to result in no UI updates.

It's a combo of three things:

- `react-blessed` is using an old version of `react-reconciler` which has a bug in it related to calling `useEffect`, and `react-blessed` really needs a new release that uses the latest version of `react-reconciler`
- Sorta related, React-Redux's `<Provider>` is still calling `useEffect` instead of our `useIsomorphicLayoutEffect` wrapper, but that would still fall back to actually being `useEffect` because this is running in a Node environment instead of a browser
- To fix that, we'd need to have a way for you as the end user to say "no, I really do want this to be `useLayoutEffect` to fix timing issues when running under Node", and we don't currently expose an API to do that right now.

Pasting my notes from that debugging session:

> - there's a bug somehow between `react-blessed` and `react-reconciler` that is causing `useEffect` cleanup functions to be run when they shouldn't be.  This *may* be due to `react-blessed` keeping around this `runningEffects` array, or it may be due to something odd in this specific version of `react-reconciler`.  Either way, the root cause of the behavior you're seeing is that `Provider` is unsubscribed when it shouldn't be because it was calling `useEffect` , and then having its cleanup function run when you dispatched a new Redux action and queued a UI update.  That caused a flush of passive effects, which hits this bit:
>
> ```js
> function flushPassiveEffects() {
>  if (passiveEffectCallbackHandle !== null) {
>    cancelPassiveEffects(passiveEffectCallbackHandle);
>  }
> ```
>
> *however*, I'm seeing that `passiveEffectCallbackHandle` is `undefined`, not `null`, so it's erroneously trying to call `cancelPassiveEffects()`.  That seems like a bug in this version of `react-reconciler`.
>
> That then causes `react-blessed` to try to clean up its `runningEffects` array, which nukes the effect handler

Comment: Ah. thanks so much for such a detailed walkthrough. I'll submit this as an issue for react-blessed. Is there some way that a 'consumer' of redux can actually debug these types of mismatch errors?

Comment: In theory, it's "just" code, so anyone could have investigated this.  On the other hand, it took me about 4.5 hours of detailed debugging to figure this out, literally stepping down into the guts of React-Redux, React-Blessed, and React itself - and I _wrote_ React-Redux v7 :)  I knew how both R-R and React work, and had a good idea of what places to look for problems. Anyone else could have done the same work, but having existing knowledge of the tools made it a lot easier for me to figure this out vs anyone else.

Comment: ah.. I was afraid of that. I submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/react-blessed/issues/115) though Yomguithereal may need a bit of help to fix this. It would be great if you can pin point where react-blessed may be unsubscribing.

Comment: Commented over there. A new release of `react-blessed` that uses the latest `react-reconciler` _should_ fix this.